# How to limit access for dowloading list item's attachment file

Tags: sharepoint

How to limit access for dowloading list item's attachment file for all users except users that are in the group of administrators?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the answer which you're looking for...
I would suggest to go with **item level permissions** on the library, where you give specific permissions to specific users/user groups.

Example:

1. Create a SharePoint Designer workflow which works with item level
   permissions on the library.
2. Attach this workflow to the library, the workflow runs whenever
       there is an item created.